# selection option value is populate depends on user given textbox value in php

Tags: php, html, textbox, dropdown

i could design website. it have textbox input and selection input types. i need to populate the selection option value depends on user input value.how can i do?
thanks in advance!

```
<input type="text" name="name">

    <?php if(isset($_POST['name'])=="abcd"){$cir="1";} 
      elseif(isset($_POST['name'])=="efgh"){$cir="2";} 
      elseif(isset($_POST['name'])=="ijkl"){$cir="3";} ?>

    <label>Select Circle:</label>
           <select id="cir" name="cir">
    <option value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST['cir'])&&$_POST['cir']=="1")
 {echo 'selected="selected"';}?>>tamil</option>
    <option value="2" <?php if(isset($_POST['cir'])&&$_POST['cir']=="2")
 {echo 'selected="selected"';}?>>english</option>
    <option value="3" <?php if(isset($_POST['cir'])&&$_POST['cir']=="3")
 {echo 'selected="selected"';}?>>hindi</option>
```

Comment: what the issue it's giving error?

Comment: cannot select anything automatically.

Comment: user input value and select drop down value should be same?